# NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module in C# Unity 5

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, unity-game-engine

This is for my graduation project. The game idea briefly is to help students practice programming by providing some interesting missions that require a C# code solution something like codingame.com, when the user produces the correct output the result is visualised in a Unity scene.

I am using a C# compiler plugin to compile the user's code in the Unity 5 run-time. Everything is working fine (each scene alone start playing the scene in the editor and stopping it) but when I advance from scene to the next one this error rises when I build the user's C# code in the run-time (NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module) (the error always rises in the second scene or the next scene).

The Error:

```
NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJDIC.png)

The Line that produces the error:

```
this.assemblyReferences = domain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();
```

assemblyRefrences is an array of strings: string[] assemblyReferences;

this line is in a script called ScriptBundleLoader in its constructor

Comment: Add the code where the error happens, also add the exception as text, not as image.

Comment: I added them both but I will write them again: the line which produces the error is : this.assemblyReferences = domain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.Location).ToArray() and the error is NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error happens because you are trying to get the location of an in-memory assembly (the ones you have created on the fly) and those assemblies aren't located anywhere.

If you want to avoid this error try something like this:

```
this.assemblyReferences = domain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => 
{ 
    try{ return a.Location; }catch{ return null; }

}).Where(s => s != null).ToArray();
```

EDIT:

As Jon Skeet pointed it can be used "IsDynamic" instead of trapping the exception:

```
this.assemblyReferences = domain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
    .Select(a => a.Location)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Would using `Assembly.IsDynamic` not work? Catching an exception seems like a really nasty way of handling this, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it will, I didn't event knew it existed :D. Updating answer.

Comment: is dynamic doesn't exist and produce an error @JonSkeet

Comment: @loaymansour: In that case I'd investigate the other properties that *are* available, to avoid catching exceptions for this.